# Python: Getting data from a function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to get data from this function:

```
def read_images(path, sz=None):
"""Reads the images in a given folder, resizes images on the fly if size is given.

Args:
    path: Path to a folder with subfolders representing the subjects (persons).
    sz: A tuple with the size Resizes

Returns:
    A list [X,y]

        X: The images, which is a Python list of numpy arrays.
        y: The corresponding labels (the unique number of the subject, person) in a Python list.
"""
c = 0
X,y = [], []
for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for subdirname in dirnames:
        subject_path = os.path.join(dirname, subdirname)
        for filename in os.listdir(subject_path):
            try:
                im = Image.open(os.path.join(subject_path, filename))
                im = im.convert("L")
                # resize to given size (if given)
                if (sz is not None):
                    im = im.resize(self.sz, Image.ANTIALIAS)
                X.append(np.asarray(im, dtype=np.uint8))
                y.append(c)
            except IOError, (errno, strerror):
                print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(errno, strerror)
            except:
                print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
                raise
        c = c+1
return [X,y]
```

The problem is that when I call the function

```
[X,y] = read_images('/Trainer')
```

where Trainer is the folder that have the images. 
Now, when I call this function, the function can't reach the folder and the values of X and y are still empty. I tried to print X and print y and both values where X=[] y=[]
I tried also to do it like this

```
TrainerPath = "C:\Users\Eng. Aladdin Hammodi\Desktop\recognizer\Trainer"
[X,y] = read_images(TrainerPath)
```

but still have the same thing. What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried listing your files using `os.listdir('C:\Users\Eng. Aladdin Hammodi\Desktop\recognizer\Trainer')`?

Comment: No, I haven't. What exactly I should add to the code?

Comment: Exactly what I wrote above. Add it at the beginning and print the output.

Comment: I got this Error os.listdir('C:\Users\Eng. Aladdin Hammodi\Desktop\recognizer\Trainer')
WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\Users\\Eng. Aladdin Hammodi\\Desktop\recognizer\\Trainer/*.*'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\` symbol escapes characters in your string. Try using a raw string modifier, like this: 
`TrainerPath = r"C:\Users\Eng. Aladdin Hammodi\Desktop\recognizer\Trainer"`

Comment: Have you debugged it? What does os.walk(...) return, just an empty generator or an error? at which point in the code does it break?

Comment: File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\shape_base.py", line 234, in vstack
    return _nx.concatenate([atleast_2d(_m) for _m in tup], 0)
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
>>>

Comment: This is specific to how you concatenate numpy arrays, can't say anything without looking at the data. Perhaps try posting a separate question since this is unrelated to this one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44862551/python-valueerror-all-the-input-array-dimensions-except-for-the-concatenation
I've posted it here

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you escape the "\" - either by putting and r before the path ( r'C:\Users....') or like 'C:\\Users...'?